# candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 3rd argument

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Calculate nth power of P (both p and n are positive integer) using a recursive function myPowerFunction(int p, int n, int &currentCallNumber). currentCallNumber is a reference parameter and stores the number of function calls made so far. myPowerFunction returns the nth power of p.

```
int myPowerFunction(int p, int n, int &z)
{
    z++;
    if(n==1)return p;
    else if(n==0)return 1;
    else if(n%2==0)return myPowerFunction(p,n/2,z)*myPowerFunction(p,n/2,z);
    else return myPowerFunction(p,n/2,z)*myPowerFunction(p,n/2,z)*p;
}

int main()
{
    cout << myPowerFunction(3,4,1);
}
```

Comment: Please format this code.

Answer (score 15):

You need a variable to pass as the third argument in main_program. You can't pass a constant as a non-const reference.

```
int count = 0;
std::cout << myPowerFunction(3, 4, count) << 'n';
std::cout << count << '\n';
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have* to give a reference as parameter as many here state.
But yes, your input for `z` cannot be modified as it comes from read-only memory. Treat the input for `z` as `const`, copy `z` internally and give the copy as reference. Then your desired usage works:

```
int myPowerFunction(int p, int n, const int &z) // z is now const !
{
    int _z = z + 1; // copy !
    if (n == 1) return p;
    else if (n == 0) return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0) return myPowerFunction(p, n /2 , _z) * myPowerFunction(p, n / 2, _z);
    else return myPowerFunction(p, n / 2, _z) * myPowerFunction(p, n / 2, _z) * p;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << myPowerFunction(3, 4, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Third parameter expects a lvalue, so you cannot pass numeric constant there, so possible solution can be:

```
int z = 1;
cout<< myPowerFunction(3,4,z);
```

or better to create a function that calls recursive one:

```
int myPowerFunction(int p, int n)
{
    int z = 1;
    return myPowerFunction(p,n,z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `myPowerFunction(3,4,1)` the literal `1` cannot be passed to a non `const` reference as it is a prvalue [basic.lval].  You need to store the value into a variable and then use that variable when calling the function.

```
int z = 0;
std::cout << myPowerFunction(3, 4, z);
```